# Finding modulus of complex number z in given equation

Tags: complex-numbers

> If complex number $z$ satisfying

> $6z^5+5iz^4+5iz-6=0$.

> Then $|z|=$

I am trying to factor

$6z^5+5iz^4+5iz-6=0$

$6(z^5-1)+5iz(z^3+1)=0$

But I did not getting any common factor

I am also trying to factorise using

$i^2=-1$

$6z^5+5iz^4+5iz+6i^2=0$

$z^4(6z+5i)+i(5z+6i)=0$

I could not get any common factor

How do I find $z$ and then $|z|$

Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: FYI, your polynomial has a similar form to the one asked about in [Modulus of complex root](/q/3629433) (found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%246z%5E5%2B5iz%5E4%2B5iz-6%3D0%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%7Cz%7C%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Acomplex&p=1)), with this [answer](/a/3629456) there likely to be of the most use to you, along with the answers at the duplicate question it's closed of at [If $11z^{10}+10iz^9+10iz-11 = 0$. Then possible value of $\mid z \mid,$ is](/q/669209).

Comment: another way to solve is to notice that $z \ne 0$ so $\frac{1}{z^4}=-\frac{6z+5i}{5iz-6}=\frac{z+5i/6}{1+\overline{5i/6}z}$; but now it is an easy exercise to show that RHS preserves the unit circle (being a disc automorhism $\frac{z+a}{1+\bar a z}, a=5i/6, |a|<1$) and also its interior and exterior, while LHS preserves the unit circle but switches the interior with the exterior, so any such $z$ must perforce satisfy $|z|=1$

Answer (score 1):

we substitute $z = r cis(θ)$ into the equation:

$6(r cis(θ))^5 + 5i(r cis(θ))^4 + 5i(r cis(θ)) - 6 = 0$

Next, we expand the powers:

$6r^5 cis(5θ) + 5ir^4 cis(4θ) + 5ir cis(θ) - 6 = 0$

Now, we equate the real and imaginary parts separately to zero.

$6r^5 cos(5θ) + 5ir^4 cos(4θ) = 0 and 5ir^4 sin(4θ) - 6 = 0$

Dividing the second equation by $5ir^4$ gives:
$sin(4θ) = 6/5ir$.

From the first equation,

$6r^5 cos(5θ) = 0$, so either $r = 0$ or $cos(5θ) = 0$

And since we cannot have |r|=0, because it doesn't make sense for the magnitude, so we have
cos(5θ) = 0.

This gives us $θ = π/5 + 2πn$ for some integer n.

Now, substituting this into the second equation, we get:

$6/5ir = sin(4θ) = sin(4(π/5 + 2πn)) = -sin(4π/5) = -0.3090169943749474$

so we have

$r^4 = -6/(5i*0.3090169943749474) = -1.9396926207859084$

and finally, the magnitude is given by the absolute value of this

$|z| = \sqrt{r^2} = |-1.9396926207859084| = 1.9396926207859084$

So the magnitude of the complex number z is approximately 1.94

Keep in mind that this is only one of the solutions of the equation, there are other solutions as well in the form of $cis(nπ/5 + 2πn)$ where n is an integer